# How to send mail(gmail mail) programmatically without using SMTP server

Tags: c#, email, gmail, shared-hosting

I am trying to send mail(using Gmail) using SMTP but somehow server is blocking to send emails.(Our application is hosted on GoDaddy server).

And it is showing below error,

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 185.107.232.247:587

Comment: Hi, Rakesh. You will get a better response (and fewer downvotes!) if you supply some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: have you contacted with suppport?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637866/sending-mail-without-installing-an-smtp-server  Pretty sure that there needs to be an SMTP server somewhere - even if you don't have one locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending mail without installing an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637866/sending-mail-without-installing-an-smtp-server)

Comment: SMTP is how to send email, you cant not use smtp

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the change to your Godaddy account.  "Check the SSL Full-time box"
2. Activate your gmail account. Check the SSL box. My settings are
      smtpout.secureserver.net   Port 465
      name and password of your godaddy account
      SSL box checked.
3. Once gmail is working, GO BACK and uncheck the Godaddy account SSL box referenced in 1, the gmail account still works.

Comment: I just gave an example of Gmail. actually, It is blocking all SMTP servers. like HotMail, sending blue etc. That's I want to know is there any way to send mail without using SMTP servers?